# How do I enable Visual Studio Community 2017 Debug cscript

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, vbscript

I recently installed Visual Studio Community 2017 with the intention to debug some Visual Basic Script files.

I have seen the suggestion to start VS as an Admin, then change the VS options to enable the script option under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Just-In-Time, and then re-debug it again.

I followed this procedure but - the Debugging feature does not appear.

A little lost and confused.

Assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I enable Visual Studio Community 2017 Debug cscript

Have you update your Visual Studio to the latest version? If not, please update your Visual Studio and try it again.

Because there is an issue fixed at Visual Studio 15.3 Preview 2. You can check the workaround in this feedback:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30845/vs2017-script-jit-debugging-is-not-working.html

Hope this helps.